# Push same webserver config to multiple front ends

Tags: debian, configuration, webserver

We are using a load balancer for our web servers (3 debian clones).
I was wondering if it was possible to push the same config onto the three web servers and restart each instance all in one shot so as to avoid differences in configs and human errors?

I guess an ssh script could do it but is there no nice gui/webadmin/ready made thingy that does that?

Comment: This is what configuration management is for. Look at tools like Puppet, Chef, Ansible, etc.